# Is the Photos To Disk third party app still available?

Tags: photos

I want to convert a photoslibrary file to a system of folders corresponding to Photos events with jpg images instead of the Apple Photos format. An earlier thread (started by Manchineel) said that Photos to Disk can do this, but the link given (https://en.freedownloadmanager.org/Mac-OS/Photos-To-Disk.html) says the link is gone and the website http://www.photos-to-disk.com/ is expired.  Does anyone know where I can purchase this software?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! I'm a little confused; is there something about Photo's built-in export functionality that won't work? You said "with jpg images instead of the Apple Photos format"; however Photos supports exporting to JPEG with the builtin option.

Answer (score 1):

The website is available in the Wayback Machine, and version 2.1 can actually be downloaded through there, although the newer version 3.5 cannot be.

https://web.archive.org/web/20180609143433/http://photos-to-disk.com/downloadbuy.html

The bigger problem, though, is there's no way to buy a license key anymore, because the developer's FastSpring page is no longer available. Unfortunately, I don't think there's a way around this.

As a user of an older version of OS X (10.9), I run into this problem all the time while trying to find compatible software, and it's very frustrating! If you're a developer reading this, please consider making a public license key available somewhere before closing shop—future generations may thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Photos to Disk wasn't updated after Mojave, so even if you managed to download it from somewhere, it won't work for newer versions of Photos. You may check out the [Photos Takeout](https://www.photostakeout.com) website (or the [App Store page](https://apps.apple.com/app/id1500714691)) - it should be able to do what you want.